# What's the Bow Weapon's enchantability?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The Minecraft Wiki [Enchanting](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#How_Enchantments_Are_Chosen) webpage lists a lot of mathmatical formulae and charts all designed to help us understand how enchanting works in Minecraft. I pretty much understand all of it.

Here's an excerpt for clarity:

> The first thing that Minecraft does is apply *two modifiers* to the base enchantment level. Each modifier is restricted to a certain range, with numbers close to the middle of the range more common than those near the ends.
> *The first modifier is based on the item's "enchantability,"* which depends on the material and the type of the item (see the table below). Minecraft picks a number between 0 and the enchantability, then adds that number plus one to the enchantment level.

Which keys off of this formula:

`modified enchantment level = enchantment level + Random(0, enchantability) + 1`

However, since the new addition of Bow Enchants in patch 1.1 I've become slightly grey on the idea of the enchantibility of a Bow, the table on the website *does not* give the enchantability for bows, however. Does anyone know it?

Edit: To clarify, from John in a comment below:

> Enchantability is a special property of an item. It is a special number that helps choose which enchantment you get. So, he's asking what this special number is for bows, he's not asking what enchantments you can give a bow, or how high these enchantments go.

Comment: It looks like your question should be answered by http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46853/what-enchantments-can-bows-have

Comment: @murgatroid: That question does not answer this one. He wants to know the enchantibility level of bows. Enchantibility is listed on the wiki for other items, but not for bows.

Comment: @JakeKing Oh. I see now

Comment: @Pureferret: Thanks for the edit, I was unaware the question would cause such confusion the state it was previously in. I figured the wiki link would solve all that but apparently you have to slap people in the face with some things.

Comment: I see two close votes for duplicate, what question have I duplicated pray tell?

Comment: No worries! Slapping applied!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wiki has been updated. Huzzah!

> Step One - Applying modifiers to the enchantment level

> The first thing that Minecraft does is apply two modifiers to the base enchantment level. Each modifier is restricted to a certain range, with numbers close to the middle of the range more common than those near the ends.

> The first modifier is based on the item's "enchantability," which depends on the material and the type of the item (see the table below). Minecraft picks a number between 0 and the enchantability, then adds that number plus one to the enchantment level. **Bows have an enchantability of 1 for this purpose.**

Shoot...SCORE!

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting)